# How to increase dc-tableview.js (DC.js, Crossfilter, data tables, ajax) performance?

Tags: ajax, performance, datatables, dc.js, crossfilter

I am using a [dc-tableview](https://github.com/karenpommeroy/dc-tableview) table based on data tables with around **1000 rows and 20 columns** (most of them are small integers) but the table takes mostly between 3-6 seconds to load at pageload.

**DeferRender is activated** (true) to render only the current page (5 rows).

As a data source I use the **crossfilter's dimensions** (accessed by .columns([data: "...")])
The data is currently saved in a javascript csv-string and used by the crossfilter.
I use ajax to load the page.

**Are there any other performance optimizations for the dc-tableview table?**

***Edit***: I could increase the performance a bit.
At the moment timings look like this (**DOM: 1.48s, Load 4.36s**):
[image]

I have no big timings in network tab (cordova.js is missing in browser).
[image]

The dc-tableview.js table takes about **500ms to 1000ms** to load (when I log it in the console). So this is **1/3 to 1/2 of the whole DOM-Render** time.

Peformance Record looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Do you think that can still be improved? Any other ideas?

The code is quite complex so I would need to know what part of the code you need to see.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Have you looked at devtools to see where the bottleneck occurs?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
I have edit the post. Any other ideas?

Comment: The flamegraph under Performance should show you which functions are taking the most time. I'm curious if it's the rendering or preprocessing of data that is taking so long. I don't have an example handy in order to try this out. I think [dc.datatables.js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.datatables.js/) uses the same techniques but I don't see a performance problem with the default example, which has more rows but less columns.

Comment: Of course, just recording the performance can make the page quite slow, but it should give you an idea of relative costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, I found some optimizations for the general load.

The table takes around **500ms** to load, which is not that much but still a number - probably due to the large dc-tableview.bs.min.js file (**100'000+ rows** when not minified).

I ask myself if and how easy it is to clean it up (maybe delete unused functions like the export buttons and stuff). There is a lighter version of the .js available on [github](https://github.com/karenpommeroy/dc-tableview) but I need the "move column" functionality, which is only availbable in full mode.

**This is how I could optimize the peformance:**

1. Use **events** to defer the load of not critical functions (gets loaded after first rendering):

for browser:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
...
});
```

for mobile (cordova):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function (event){
...
});
```

2. Put everything (the source data which gets parsed) into **cache** so it must only be parsed once.
3. **Minify** all .js and .css
4. Resize **images** and optimize compression
5. **Reduce** number of dc-tableview **columns** whenever possible

Any other recommendations?